# Getting HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name null in Web Api 2 log in through angular 4

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

```
 bool iss = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
 if(iss) {
          UserManager.FindByName(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
          string name = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
}


<authentication mode="None" />
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
```

- I am getting name null and Is authenticated is true login through
  asp.net web api with angular 2
- Web Config is given above i also try mode="Windows"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolve My Issue i use `GenerateUserIdentityAsync()` Method Instead of this

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
```

My Code is bellow Working fine Now!

```
 public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var userStore = new CustomUserStore(new ApplicationDbContext());
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser, long>(userStore);
        var user = await manager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
        if (user != null)
        {
            // var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);

            ClaimsIdentity identity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("UserId", user.Id.ToString()));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Username", user.UserName.ToString()));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Email", user.Email));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("UserRole", new RoleManagerBusinessLogic().GetRoleNameByRoleId(user.Roles.FirstOrDefault().RoleId)));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("LoggedOn", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()));
            context.Validated(identity);
        }
        else
            return;

    }
```